# Помогите пожалуйста: NameError: name 'nameOFcity' is not defined

Tags: python-3.x

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import os
import sys
import webbrowser
import pyttsx3
import pyowm
import datetime
import time
owm = pyowm.OWM('f58349d7f89f82766b104bc8b3f318b1',language='ru')

engine = pyttsx3.init()
def talk(words):
    print(words)
    engine.say(words)
    engine.runAndWait()
talk('Здравствуйте, попросите что-нибудь : ')

def commands():
    r = sr.Recognizer()

    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print('Говорите : ')
        r.pause_threshold = 0.5
        r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source, duration=1)
        audio = r.listen(source)
    try:
        exersize = r.recognize_google(audio, language="ru-Ru").lower()
        talk('Вы сказали : ' + exersize)
    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        talk('Я вас не поняла ')
        exersize = commands()

    return exersize

def makeSomeThing(exersize):
    if 'открой гугл' in exersize:
        talk('Сию минуту' )
        url = 'https://www.google.com/'
        webbrowser.open(url)
    elif 'имя' in exersize:
        talk('Меня зовут Данелия')
    elif 'время' in exersize:
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        talk("Сейчас " + str(now.hour) + ':' + str(now.minute))
    elif 'стоп' in exersize:
        talk('Да, конечно')
        sys.exit()
    elif 'погода' in exersize:
        def city():
            talk('Скажите город в котором хотите узнать погоду: ')
            nameOFcity = r.recognize_google(audio, language="ru-Ru").lower()
        observation = owm.weather_at_place(nameOFcity)
        w = observation.get_weather()
        temp = w.get_weather('celsius')["temp"]
        talk(' В городе ' + str(nameOFcity) + ' сейчас ' + w.get_detailed_status() + '\n')
        talk('Температура в районе ' + str(temp) + '\n\n')

while True:
    makeSomeThing(commands())
```

Comment: Переменная `nameOFcity` не объявлена в области видимости блока `elif 'погода' in exersize`, но вы пытаетесь к ней обращаться.

Comment: Можете написать нужную часть кода , а то я не сильно врубился :)

Comment: Уберите строку def city(): и по одной табуляции в двух последующих строках.

Comment: У вас получилась как бы "функция внутри функции", но вы её не вызываете как функцию всё-равно, поэтому надо её преобразовать в обычный код

Comment: Спасибо большое